# Differennce in MYSQL Master slave DISK SPACE

Tags: mysql

I am using percona_mysql_5.6, both master and slave are in sync as terms of replication and table  wise records are also same. However there is a difference is the disk space consumed. The slave is consuming relatively more space than master. Even the mysql.conf is same for both master and slave.
Any idea why this might happen or any leads that i can check?

Comment: Maybe you can get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com since stackoverflow is for programming questions, rather than administration ones.

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs on dba.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for specific code questions.

That said, the difference is because a replica doesn't necessarily store records in exactly the same physical position in tablespace files, and it's not required to. The replica needs to store the same set of records as its source, but how it lays them out within the storage is arbitrary.

If it bothers you, I suggest using `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to re-write the tablespaces. This should defragment the tables on both source and replica instances, and make them use nearly the same amount of space.